# Cannot edit and focus textboxes in Tinymce windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

When I use Tinymce in my modal, all textboxes and textareas in any window in tinymce editor like Source code and textboxes in "Insert Video" will uneditable and unfocusable!
and when I disable javascript in browser it will be ok!

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#testText',
    theme: "modern",
    width: '100%',
    plugins: [
        "code", "media"
    ],
    content_css: "css/content.css",
    toolbar: "",
    style_formats: [{
        title: 'Example 1',
        inline: 'span',
        classes: 'example1'
    }, {
        title: 'Example 2',
        inline: 'span',
        classes: 'example2'
    }, {
        title: 'Table styles'
    }, {
        title: 'Table row 1',
        selector: 'tr',
        classes: 'tablerow1'
    }],
    font_formats: "Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;" +
        "Google='Google, tahoma, arial;" +
        "Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;",
});
```